# Help with reminder script in Bash

Tags: bash, scripts

I have stacked trying to make a simple reminder script which can compare the running date with the date that a file has. for example I have a file that contains:

```
Apr 25 2015 cycling \n
Apr 26 2015 football \n
.\n
.\n
.\n
.\n
```

i want to compare the running date (reading the file line by line) with the date of the file and if they match then I want to be printed the specific line in my screen. can you help me please? I am trying so hard...

Answer (score 5):

An easy way would be to use `grep`:

```
date +'^%b %d %Y' | grep -f- your_file
```

Answer (score 3):

Using only `bash`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
today="$(date +"%b %d %Y")"
while IFS= read -r line; do
   [[ $line =~ ^$today ]] && echo "$line"
done </path/to/file.txt
```

- The `today` variable stores that day's formatted date
- `while IFS= read -r line` will read each line from `file.txt` and save it as variable `line`
- `[[ $line =~ ^$today ]]` will test if the `line` has started with the today's date
- `&& echo "$line"` will print the `line` if the previous command returns an exit code `0` i.e. the previous condition is true.